# Add shipping charges before login or entering customer details in onepage review block

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, onepage-checkout, review

I am using onepage checkout extension, I wish to add shipping charges of products to be added in review block before login and entering customer information.
Let us take an example, product having a cost of  Rs.430 and its shipping charge is Rs.80(set from backend for every product), then I just want to show 430+80 in review block, without entering any details and before login at onepage checkout page.Kindly refer to the attached screenshot for the same.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by using an event observer, you can use the `"sales_quote_collect_totals_before"` event to add your shipping method like `"flatrate"` and set the necessary values and display on review page, please find the code below and use it as per your requirement :)

Event:

```
<sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
     <observers>
         <set_shipping_cartpage>
              <type>singleton</type>
              <class>modulename/observer</class>
              <method>yourmethodname</method>
              </set_shipping_cartpage>
         </observers>
</sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
```

Observer:

```
$country = 'US'; //your country code
$postcode = '';
$city = '';
$regionId = '';
$region = '';
$code = 'modulename_standard';

$quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

if (!$quote->getId()) return;

$shippingMethod = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();

if ($shippingMethod) return;

$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();

$model = Mage::getModel("modulename/carrier_method_standard");

$subTotal = $quote->getSubtotal();

$price = 0.00; // Add your shipping price

$shippingAddress
    ->setCountryId($country)
    ->setRegionId($regionId)
    ->setPostcode($postcode)
    ->setShippingMethod($code)
    ->setShippingAmount($price)
    ->setCollectShippingRates(true);

$shippingAddress->save();

$quote->save();
```

After that you need to override the collectotals to add you shipping like I mentioned above `"carrier_method_standard"` and on checkout page override the progress block to add your functions to display your before login shipping method. Hope that will help you to integrate the same :)

Accept it if that helps.